# Windows 8 Alternative to PythonCard?

Tags: python, user-interface, pythoncard

I have a Windows 8 and PythonCard would not install because of a missing Dll file. (MSVCR72) I tried to install the .dll through multiple methods and it did not work so I now assume that the problem is because I have a Windows 8. (because most websites I looked at was a forum for Windows 7 problems and users who owned a Windows 7) (I'm using Python 2.7.6 btw)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using cx_freeze and pygame together(for windows). [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) is some other GUI tools. You could also try cx_freeze with tkinter. I use cx_freeze myself. If you use pygame with cx_freeze you have to add `import pygame._view` to the beginning of your script.